# Electrical power shutting off while driving. 2002 Buick Rendezvous CXL

Tags: electrical, wiring, security

I've had this problem for about a week now. While driving the car radio, instrument cluster, A/C and lights shut off intermittently and I can hear clicking from relays in the fusebox. The engine runs perfectly fine during this. This "event" happens completely randomly i.e. when the key is in the ignition without the engine running, without the key, and when the engine is running. The duration is also random from half a second to non stop off, on, off, on.

**KEY INFO:** The intermittent power outtage doesn't happen when the SECURITY light is on. I can drive for miles like this but power doors, windows, key FOB and A/C doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

After working on the car for days I found the cause of the problem. **A bad rear windshield wiper motor connector.** The ground wire had a short and since the motor and rear hatch lock share the same ground it would sometimes unlock by itself. I'm guessing that's also the reason why the power wouldn't cut out when the security light came on since it disables all the power locks. The security light would come on because the passkey sensor would lose power and it's signal with the key FOB. **All of this because of one cable.**